# Dynamic dependent dropdowns on Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to add the following functionality on a google form -

I need to have two dropdowns on the form-

Dropdown1 values are being populated from the google sheet using a script.
Dropdown2 values must also be populated from the google sheet BUT must change based on the value selected in Dropdown1 on the form.

Since Dropdown1 has many values in the list, using the "go to section based on answer" is not an option to show Dropdown2.

How can I implement this cascading/dependent dropdown functionality dynamically on the google form (I guess using the google script and google sheet)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible on a Google Form

Comment: You can't in forms, you would have to make sections and use go to section to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible using Google Forms.*

#### Explanation:

In order to change the contents of later dropdowns based on the selected answer in a previous question, direct access to the browser session must be retrieved by Google's server *before* form submission. This isn't done.

Until a form has been submitted by the user, giving explicit permission to send the answers they have provided, the answers are not communicated to Google's servers and as such later questions can not change based on previous answers. Implementing this would be a privacy issue so I can not forsee Google creating this option in the future either.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation!