# How to auto fill Google form with multi drop list

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

How to auto fill Google form with multi drop list from google sheet data

I have two table data with one-to-many relationship:

1. department (D1 , D2, D3...)
2. class (C1, C2, C3...)
   In google form, i have 2 drop list for 2 object.
   I want when user select one department on drop list 1, drop list 2 will auto fill all class of department on drop list 1.
   Please help me, many thank

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87413/is-there-a-way-to-specify-multiple-conditions-for-go-to-section-feature-in-goo or would you like to provide sample data and explain thoroughly your concern?

Comment: You have tagged this as `google-forms` AND `google-sheets` but it seems that it is really a **forms** question. If I understand you correctly, you want Google Forms to dynamically populate a drop down list based on the response to another question. Unfortunately Google Forms does not have this feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic dependent dropdowns on Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418531/dynamic-dependent-dropdowns-on-google-form)